# How to Create New Lines of Content on Update Azure DevOps Wiki on CLI Command Line

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-wiki

I'm trying to create a table in Azure DevOps Wiki using the Azure CLI command `az DevOps wiki page update`. The value of the `--content` parameter that I'm sending contains \n which I'm led to believe creates a new line in the wiki page, but it doesn't seem to work, instead, it looks like this:[image]

The --content parameter value looks like this:

```
"# Main Heading\n\n## Subheading\n\n| **Column Header**          | **Header 1** | **Header 2** | **Header 3** |  **Header 4** | **Header 5**    |\n| -----------------      | ------- | ------- | ------- | -------- | ---------- |\n| Item 1 | 1.1.1 | 1.1.1 | 1.1.1 | 1.1.1 | **1.1.1** |\n| Item 2 | 2.2.2 | 2.2.2 | 2.2.2 | 2.2.2 | **2.2.2** |\n| Item 3 | 3.3.3 | 3.3.3 | 3.3.3 | 3.3.3 | **3.3.3** |\n| Item 4 | 4.4.4 | 4.4.4 | 4.4.4 | 4.4.4 | **4.4.4** |\n"
```

It feels like some kind of automatic escaping is happening somewhere.

Does anyone know how I can achieve a new line in this scenario, please?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace ``\n`` with `\`n` to embed actual newlines in your string.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I tried that and the wiki page received a truncated string which terminated at the first `\`n`.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/manage-wikis?view=azure-devops) don't talk about escaping, unfortunately. Note that ``\`` is _not_ special to PowerShell, so these escape sequences are passed verbatim to the `az` CLI, which, it seems, also retains them verbatim. You can probably _work around_ your problem by creating a temporary file (with actual newlines) and using it with the `--file-path` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use md file and pass it as parameter.

text.md

```
#Updated Employee List
 
Here is the updated list of employees:
 
| Employee ID | Name          | Department    |
|-------------|---------------|---------------|
| 001         | John Smith    | HR            |
| 002         | Jane Doe      | Engineering   |
| 003         | Michael Brown | Marketing     |
```

and then

```
version=$(az devops wiki page show --org https://dev.azure.com/kmadej0455/ --project kmadej --path '/test' --wiki kmadej.wiki --query eTag -o tsv)

az devops wiki page update --organization https://dev.azure.com/kmadej0455/ --project kmadej --wiki kmadej.wiki --version $version --path '/test'  --file-path text.md            --encoding utf-8
```